# What parameters do i have to send to a server?

Tags: c, unix, tcp, client, knx

I can't send a valid request to a Server.
I have this protocol description but I don't understand what thing i have to send with socat to the server.

> **header** Must always be transmitted in full, even if the command does not
>   require any parameters.
>
> **command** This is a single letter whose case is important (commands 'A' and 'a' are
>   very different, indeed, for example). It is 8 bit in size.
>
> **param** 1 This is a 16 bit numeric parameter. It is in network byte order and
>   mostly used to specify KNX device addresses or data lengths.

My problem comes from `param`. I have to send a 16 bit numeric parameter with null value.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 3):

Ordinarily, a "null value" just means you send zero.

If the server socket is `sock`, then this would send 16 bits:

```
send (sock, "\0\0", 2, 0);
```

Comment: Actually, because a string literal always has a null character appended to it, `send(sock, "\0", 2, 0)` would suffice. But wouldn't it be better to build of the entire message (header, command, and parameter) into a single buffer and then `send()` the whole thing at once?

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: yes, it would better, but the OP didn't specify what to put there, and anyway I wanted to keep it simple.